# Boolean NOT in solr query

Tags: solr

How do I pick/ delete all the documents from Solr using the boolean NOT notion?

i.e. How do I delete all the documents from Solr who's id does NOT start with A59?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use `-` to indicate `NOT`.

For example, to query  documents with id not starting with A59, the query would be: `-id:A59*`, that is: `/solr/select/?q=-id:A59*`

To delete by query, post the query in a delete message to the update handler, as specified [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#head-f5553a8214869b11708ad5476e05e7b05a024c23).

EDIT: `NOT` (all uppercase) can also be used as boolean operator

Answer (score 12):

Exclamation works for NOT as well, so:

```
/solr/select/?q=!id:A59*
```

should work in the case above.

Comment: This answer didn't work where as the one above did, I am not sure but I think `!` might actually have slightly different semantics

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that a negative delete by query works.  See this Jira ticket:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-381

They do say that there is a workaround to prefix in a :, but I do not have any luck with that.

This does not work (same with using NOT)
java -Ddata=args -jar /opt/solr/example/exampledocs/post.jar "-userid:*"
java -jar /opt/solr/example/exampledocs/post.jar *.xml

Adding in a : gives a syntax error (same with using NOT)
java -Ddata=args -jar /opt/solr/example/exampledocs/post.jar ": -userid:*"
java -jar /opt/solr/example/exampledocs/post.jar *.xml

SimplePostTool: version 1.4
SimplePostTool: POSTing args to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Solr returned an error #400 Error parsing Lucene query
SimplePostTool: version 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Using the - symbol in-front of the files to implies that exclude that particular value. It will give result like **NOT Equal**

The following is sample url query string where. I have kept "**&fq=-HQ_City_Code:MEL**",

It will skip all the result which is having **HQ_City_Code** value **MEL**.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/HQ_SOLR_Hotels/select?q=*:*&fq=HQ_National_Code:TH&fq=HQ_TYPE:hotel_EN&fq=HQ_Country_Code:AU&**fq=-HQ_City_Code:MEL**&wt=json&indent=true
```

Answer (score 0):

before deleting please ensure that the ids that you are referring to is string and in no way would be formed by two terms combined .
The way I would do it is read the data from solr from a script and do a singular delete or in batches , because it provides a better control and validations over each ids which reduces the risk of wrong deletion
Hence 
1 read the data from solr from a script using 
/solr/select/?q=id:A59*

2 verify and validate the ids

3 delete them one by one or in a group of 10 ids at once

Regards

Rajat

Answer (score 0):

As [Mauricio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379890/643761) stated:

Use the - symbol to indicate what you want exclude in your query.
The following two queries will delete all documents except the ones that begin with A59.

```
GET http://<url>/solr/<core>/update?stream.body=<delete><query>-id:A59*</query></delete>
GET http://<url>/solr/<core>/update?stream.body=<commit/>
```

The first line does the delete operation.
The second line does the commit.